# Am I being monitored?

Tags: macbook-pro, remote-control, activity-monitor, malware, parental-controls

I have a few questions to ask regarding the parental controls.

I have a MacBook Pro OS X version 10.9.4. and it was bought by my ex to help me with my medical schooling. We’re no longer together. And I’ve caught him logging into my emails somehow recently. Don’t know if he hacked into it or just came across my password.

So, lately while bored I got curious about my computer and discovered Console and started to observe what was gong on and to my amazement, I had noticed many many things. i have disabled the bluetooth sharing and everything else because it seemed that my computer is being monitored. I’m just not sure. But what sticks out the most for me is the Parental controls remote issue. I have disabled everything. So I think.

```
Jul 24 09:09:03 (MYNAME)-mbp parentalcontrolsd[957]: StartObservingFSEvents [849:] -- *** StartObservingFSEvents started event stream

Jul 24 11:22:01 (MYNAME)-mbp com.apple.preference.universalaccess.remoteservice[1179]: Bogus event received by listener connection:
<error: 0x7fff737b0b50> { count = 1, contents =
"XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x7fff737b0e60> { length = 18, contents = "Connection invalid" }
}
Jul 24 11:22:23 (MYNAME)-mbp System Preferences[1173]: view service marshal for <NSRemoteView: 0x7fbf8b634110> failed to forget accessibility connection due to Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "Couldn’t communicate with a helper application." (The connection was invalidated from this process.) UserInfo=0x600000274400 {NSDebugDescription=The connection was invalidated from this process.}
timestamp: 11:22:23.888 Thursday 24 July 2014
process/thread/queue: System Preferences (1173) / 0x10ee36000 / com.apple.NSXPCConnection.user.endpoint
code: line 2972 of /SourceCache/ViewBridge/ViewBridge-46.2/NSRemoteView.m in __57-[NSRemoteView viewServiceMarshalProxy:withErrorHandler:]_block_invoke
domain: communications-failure

Jul 24 11:22:44 (MYNAME)-mbp xpcd[165]: restored permissions (100600 -> 100700) on /Users/[DummyUserName]/Library/Containers/com.apple.appstore/Container.plist
Jul 24 11:22:45 (MYNAME)-mbp com.apple.SecurityServer[14]: Killing auth hosts
Jul 24 11:22:45 (MYNAME)-mbp com.apple.SecurityServer[14]: Session 100025 destroyed
Jul 24 11:22:45 (MYNAME)-mbp com.apple.SecurityServer[14]: Session 100027 created
Jul 24 11:23:06 (MYNAME)-mbp com.apple.preference.security.remoteservice[1193]: assertion failed: 13E28: liblaunch.dylib + 25164 [A40A0C7B-3216-39B4-8AE0-B5D3BAF1DA8A]: 0x25

Jul 24 11:40:32 (MYNAME)-mbp loginwindow[43]: magsafeStateChanged state changed old 1 new 2
Jul 24 11:44:30 (MYNAME)-mbp System Preferences[1173]: view service marshal for <NSRemoteView: 0x7fbf8b61c3a0> failed to forget accessibility connection due to Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "Couldn’t communicate with a helper application." (The connection was invalidated from this process.) UserInfo=0x608000663bc0 {NSDebugDescription=The connection was invalidated from this process.}
timestamp: 11:44:30.798 Thursday 24 July 2014
process/thread/queue: System Preferences (1173) / 0x10ed4f000 / com.apple.NSXPCConnection.user.endpoint
code: line 2972 of /SourceCache/ViewBridge/ViewBridge-46.2/NSRemoteView.m in __57-[NSRemoteView viewServiceMarshalProxy:withErrorHandler:]_block_invoke
domain: communications-failure

Jul 24 11:44:32 (MYNAME)-mbp com.apple.preferences.parentalcontrols.remoteservice[1218]: Parental Controls Pref Remote Service launching
Jul 24 11:44:32 (MYNAME)-mbp com.apple.preferences.parentalcontrols.remoteservice[1218]: assertion failed: 13E28: liblaunch.dylib + 25164 [A40A0C7B-3216-39B4-8AE0-B5D3BAF1DA8A]: 0x25
Jul 24 11:44:32 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Jul 24 11:44:32 (MYNAME)-mbp com.apple.preferences.parentalcontrols.remoteservice[1218]: GetICUWeekdayWeekendInfo [773] -- *** ICU lookup failed, using default values
Jul 24 11:44:32 (MYNAME)-mbp com.apple.preferences.parentalcontrols.remoteservice[1218]: Bogus event received by listener connection:
<error: 0x7fff737b0b50> { count = 1, contents =
"XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x7fff737b0e60> { length = 18, contents = "Connection invalid" }
}
Jul 24 11:44:47 (MYNAME)-mbp System Preferences[1173]: view service marshal for <NSRemoteView: 0x7fbf8b61c3a0> failed to forget accessibility connection due to Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "Couldn’t communicate with a helper application." (The connection was invalidated from this process.) UserInfo=0x60000086f200 {NSDebugDescription=The connection was invalidated from this process.}
timestamp: 11:44:47.015 Thursday 24 July 2014
process/thread/queue: System Preferences (1173) / 0x10d653000 / com.apple.NSXPCConnection.user.endpoint
code: line 2972 of /SourceCache/ViewBridge/ViewBridge-46.2/NSRemoteView.m in __57-[NSRemoteView viewServiceMarshalProxy:withErrorHandler:]_block_invoke
domain: communications-failure

Jul 24 11:44:51 (MYNAME)-mbp com.apple.preferences.users.remoteservice[1220]: assertion failed: 13E28: liblaunch.dylib + 25164 [A40A0C7B-3216-39B4-8AE0-B5D3BAF1DA8A]: 0x25
Jul 24 11:44:52 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Jul 24 11:44:52 (MYNAME)-mbp com.apple.preferences.users.remoteservice[1220]: Bogus event received by listener connection:
<error: 0x7fff737b0b50> { count = 1, contents =
"XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x7fff737b0e60> { length = 18, contents = "Connection invalid" }
}
Jul 24 11:45:14 (MYNAME)-mbp launchservicesd[55]: Application App:"System Preferences" asn:0x0-5a05a pid:1173 refs=7 @ 0x7f7f89602a70 tried to be brought forward, but isn't in fPermittedFrontApps ( ( "LSApplication:0x0-0x63063 pid=1223 "SecurityAgent"")), so denying. : LASSession.cp #1481 SetFrontApplication() q=LSSession 100004/0x186a4 queue
Jul 24 11:45:14 (MYNAME)-mbp WindowServer[85]: [cps/setfront] Failed setting the front application to System Preferences, psn 0x0-0x5a05a, securitySessionID=0x186a4, err=-13066
Jul 24 11:45:30 (MYNAME)-mbp WindowServer[85]: window 1f4 is already attached to window 1f1
Jul 24 11:45:37 (MYNAME)-mbp WindowServer[85]: _CGXGetWindowOrderingGroup: Invalid window 0x1f4
Jul 24 11:45:42 (MYNAME)-mbp com.apple.SecurityServer[14]: Killing auth hosts
Jul 24 11:45:42 (MYNAME)-mbp com.apple.SecurityServer[14]: Session 100027 destroyed
Jul 24 11:45:42 (MYNAME)-mbp com.apple.SecurityServer[14]: Session 100029 created
Jul 24 11:46:01 (MYNAME)-mbp System Preferences[1173]: view service marshal for <NSRemoteView: 0x7fbf8b61c3a0> failed to forget accessibility connection due to Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "Couldn’t communicate with a helper application." (The connection was invalidated from this process.) UserInfo=0x608000664540 {NSDebugDescription=The connection was invalidated from this process.}
timestamp: 11:46:01.114 Thursday 24 July 2014
process/thread/queue: System Preferences (1173) / 0x10ed4f000 / com.apple.NSXPCConnection.user.endpoint
code: line 2972 of /SourceCache/ViewBridge/ViewBridge-46.2/NSRemoteView.m in __57-[NSRemoteView viewServiceMarshalProxy:withErrorHandler:]_block_invoke
domain: communications-failure
```

What could this mean?? My ex has a Mac desktop at his house and at his business. I’m not sure if he’s the one monitoring my computer activities…or malware??.  But in all seriousness, I am very curious to what this means. I’m too old to be monitored….

Thank you.

Comment: Your user name appears in the log; you might want to avoid that. I’ve proposed an edit so that it’s not readily accessible, but it will still be viewable in the history. If you’d like to change that, I would recommend discussing with an admin.

Answer (score 5):

Install [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html). It's an [Outbound Firewall](http://www.intego.com/mac-security-blog/why-you-need-an-outbound-firewall/) meaning that when apps on your computer try to establish connections to other machines, you'll get a notification and be able to block the connections.

If someone is trying to monitor your computer, Little Snitch would inform you of the outgoing network connections and allow you to block them.

Answer (score 3):

First, I have the exact same messages in my log files. I also was worried, but parental controls is more of a mechanism to restrict usage of the system. In other words you would use parental controls to make the system less powerful, and as an admin you can easily turn them off.

You would go to

```
System Preferences > Parental Controls
```

as an admin, and you will be able to assure yourself that it's only Apple.

It seems that with 10.9.4 it was activated for the Guest user (Managed Preferences). It's irritating, but bearable.

That being said, [Remote Management or ARD](https://www.apple.com/ca/remotedesktop/) *is* the tool one would use in this situation to monitor a user. This requires access to the target computer. Since you've already had your email hacked, perhaps it's time to back up your personal data and take a couple of hours and wipe your system clean. Change passwords, create a new user, use your firewall, and change your iCloud info.

Reasonable precautions actually go far.

You'll probably want to start by **removing your name from the logfile you posted completely.**

Good luck with everything.

Answer (score 1):

So this is super old but just in case someone comes across this. `ViewBridge` is a way for applications to display UI in separate memory space than the main app. This is how an app can ask for your admin password and will never know the password (Apple creates a separate window on another thread that the app can't access so your password is safe).

`ViewBridge` is the name of the framework that enables this functionality, and `NSRemoteView` is a wrapper around the base `NSView` programmers normally use to display views. `NSRemoteView` displays a view that isn't from the "main" app (again, something like a password prompt). It can't display views from another computer or stream video or anything like that. It's just for displaying system views (like parental controls).

Nothing in these logs indicates remote access to your machine. In fact, it would be probably the *stupidest* program in the world that would remotely access a machine and then *log it publicly*.